# How alkanes can be prepared by aldehydes and ketones?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Preparation of alkanes by aldehydes and ketones, its chemical reaction and mechanism.

Comment: Please add additional details into the question.  What information have you found thus far? (hint: take a look at your textbook)

Comment: I need the chemical reaction

Comment: Please see our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange).

Comment: Look [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7868/why-does-hydrogen-so-easily-take-the-place-of-oxygen-in-organic-molecules-during/7884#7884)

Answer (score 3):

You want to deoxygenate the carbonyls under conditions where you do not get condensation reactions.  Do you want to pull the oxygen or dimerize to the olefins then hydrogenate?

Wolff-Kishner or Clemmensen reductions, thioacetal then Raney nickel and hydrogen.  McMurry reaction for dimerization.  Given polymethylhydrosiloxane,

Synlett 276 (2009) 
Org. Lett. 13, 584 (2011)